# vagrant issues after upgrading ubuntu from 12 to 14 (localhost)

Tags: php, apache, vagrant, lamp

I updated php and apache as well. Now my vagrant box won't reload. I consistently get this error:

```
==> default: Attempting graceful shutdown of VM...
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

shutdown -h now

Stdout from the command:



Stderr from the command:
```

If i add an index.html file it works and index.php file works with  inside, so apache seems to be running fine:

```
Index of /

[ICO]   Name    Last modified   Size    Description
Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at 192.168.33.15 Port 80
```

But after doing some research, when i vagrant ssh into my box I notice that the /var/www folder did not sync like usual. So there is essentially nothing in there which is maybe the reason why i'm getting the empty directory as apache states above as well.

Comment: `Index of /` is not an error. It's simply Apache that lists all files in the document root. It's the Apache setting `Options +Indexes` that allows for that if no default index file is found in a folder.

Comment: Thank you, i was typing fast but i knew that. =]